# Language and input made foreced stopped,how to change keyboard on android device?

Tags: stock-android

I have phone named Micro max A091(Android 4.4.2), I had rooted my phone a long ago.There is a problem that when ever I tried to open the language and input in setting, but that makes stopped the whole setting.

Is there any way to change the default keyboard without flashing or repairing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Which keyboard are you trying to get rid of? If it isn't [Google Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin), go download it from the Play Store, open the app and follow the steps. See if that fixes your issue. If you already use Google Keyboard, try downloading another keyboard like [SwiftKey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey).

Comment: And when you follow the steps on Google Keyboard or Swiftkey, you get "Unfortunately, Settings has stopped" on the step "Enable Keyboard"